# increment value of i is not working properly

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am not able to understand why value of i is not setting to zero and it's behaving like this st the start of both form value of i is set to zero but not getting the desired out in html form

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <form name="assignNone" action="" method="post">
    @csrf
      @method('PUT')
       <?php $i=0 ?>
         @foreach($users as $user)
           @if($user->name=='NONE' )
             <input type="text" name="marks[{{$i}}]" value="">
           @endif
           <?php $i++; ?>
        @endforeach
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <form name="assignabc" action="" method="post">
    @csrf
      @method('PUT')
        @if(!empty($iprnNumbers))
            <?php $i=0 ?>
                @foreach($users as $user )
                    @if($user ->name!='NONE' )
                        <input type="text" name="marks[{{$i}}]" value="">
                    @endif
                <?php $i++; ?>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </form>
</div>
```

output is showing  as

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
       <form name="assignNone" action="" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="marks[2] value="">
          <input type="text" name="marks[3] value="">
          <input type="text" name="marks[4] value="">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <form name="assignabc" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="marks[0]" value="">
        <input type="text" name="marks[1]" value="">
       </form>
    </div>
```

result i want should be something like

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
       <form name="assignNone" action="" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="marks[0] value="">
          <input type="text" name="marks[1] value="">
          <input type="text" name="marks[2] value="">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <form name="assignabc" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="marks[0]" value="">
        <input type="text" name="marks[1]" value="">
       </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: put `<?php $i++; ?>` inside `@if(...) @endif`

Comment: Misspled `name="marks[0]` should be `name="marks[0]"` quatation mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it should be `<?php $i = 0; ?>`. Notice the semicolon. Second, you need to move the increment inside the if condition, so it would look like-

```
 <?php $i++; ?>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a short example called dynamic input as example below :

```
<form name="assignNone" action="" method="post">   
  <input type="text" name="marks[]" value="one">
  <input type="text" name="marks[]" value="two">
  <input type="text" name="marks[]" value="three">
</form>
```

Then in your controller you will be able to get all `marks` values like this :

```
$marks = $request->marks; // give you an array with values
```

This will solve your problem very easily as it's easy to implement & also it's easy to understand!